# How to use VERB in url

Tags: curl

I am trying to create and API which uses VERB PUT,GET,DELETE

I can use it in curl by this

```
curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/recipes/hi
```

But how can i use similarly in url

for eg

This works

```
http://localhost:8080/recipes/hi
```

But this is not working

```
http://localhost:8080/recipes/DELETE/foo
```

How to add verb DELETE in url?

Comment: **Warning** - please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](http://superuser.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 
Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.

The HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, and OPTIONS) are applied *to* a URL. They are not elements *of* a URL.

You can see that in your cURL example: `curl -X DELETE http://localhost:8080/recipes/hi`

Here the HTTP verb is `DELETE`, while the URL is `http://localhost:8080/recipes/hi`. Verb and URL: two different things.

In general, when you enter a URL into a browser address bar, it will issue a GET request to that URL. Browsers will issue POST requests when submitting a form on a HTML page with a `method="POST"` attribute.

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/submit">
```

If you fill in this form, the browser will submit a POST request to that URL.

Browsers will not, in the normal course of events, issue PUT, DELETE, HEAD, or OPTIONS requests. They can, but it will require scripting with javascript.